# Which parts of the Zend Framework 2 can be easily replaced by custom classes?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, service-locator, servicemanager

Zend Framework 2 provides a possibility to use custom classes instead of a `invokables` delivered with the framework. E.g. `ViewHelper` classes:

```
namespace Application;

...

class Module {

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent) {
        $application = $mvcEvent->getApplication();
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
        $viewHelperManager = $serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager');
        $viewHelperManager->setInvokableClass('headmeta', 'MyNamespace\View\Helper\HeadMeta');
    }

    ...

    public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
        return array(
            ...
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                    'MyNamespace' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/MyNamespace/library/MyNamespace',
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

}
```

So, all `invocable`s (particularly the `ViewHelper`s) can be replaced. What else? Is there a list of types of classes, that can be replaced by custom ones the way like `invokables` (using the `ServiceManager` / `EventManager`)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess everything that ends up 'in' the service/plugin manager can be substituted. You can checkup places like [controller](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/PluginManager.php), [view](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/HelperPluginManager.php) or [form element](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/FormElementManager.php) plugin manager classes. You could also try to dump the whole service manager object and see what keys it holds and try to overwrite them in your `Module` class (using the same service class as the original, e.g. overwriting a factory created service with another factory).